# Where we are doing the selection of validators?

Tags: validator

I'm new to substrate, I want to explore where we are selecting the validators for current block authorisation[pos].

Can anyone help me to find out in the code for that particular functionality?

Comment: Which setup are you using, because the answer is "it depends... " as you asked the question right now.

Comment: In you genesis block there is probably a section for default validators